# Where is this segmentation fault and how to fix it?

Tags: c++

I'm new to cpp, trying to write an echo server. I don't know where the segmentation fault is and I have been trying to find it for an hour.

When I run this server and client, the server crashed after client sent message.
I'm confused, where the problem is.

There is a commenting in the code, where is the vscode stoped and pointed out with a yellow tag.

Is the **msgBuffer** went wrong or something ?

Anyone can help me?

```cpp
#define SERV_PORT 1234

#define MAXLINE 1024

int sockfd, clientfd;

void stopServer(int p) {
    close(clientfd);
    close(sockfd);
    std::cout << "Server offline" << std::endl;
    exit(0);
}

void reconnect(int p) {
    close(clientfd);
    std::cout << "Client close. " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Server listening..." << std::endl;
    clientfd = accept(sockfd, NULL, NULL);
}

class Server {
   public:
   public:
    int doBind(int argc, char const** argv) {
        memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr));
        this->servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        if (argc == 3) {
            inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &this->servaddr.sin_addr);
            this->servaddr.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[2]));
        } else {
            
            this->servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
            this->servaddr.sin_port = htons(SERV_PORT);
        }

        if (-1 == bind(sockfd, (sockaddr*)&this->servaddr, sizeof(servaddr))) {
            std::cout << "Bind error" << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

   private:
    sockaddr_in servaddr;
};

class Client {
   public:
   public:
    void doListen(int q) {
        listen(sockfd, q);
        std::cout << "Listening for request..." << std::endl;
    }

    void doAccept() { clientfd = accept(sockfd, NULL, NULL); }

>     void msgProcess(char* msgBuffer) {
>         while (1) {
>             signal(SIGINT, stopServer);
>     
>             signal(SIGPIPE, reconnect);
>             
>             memset(&msgBuffer, 0, sizeof(msgBuffer));
>     
>             recv(clientfd, &msgBuffer, MAXLINE, 0);
>     
>             // vscode stoped, and yellow tag pointed here 
>             std::cout << msgBuffer << std::endl;
>     
>             send(clientfd, &msgBuffer, sizeof(msgBuffer), 0);
>         }
>     }

   private:
    sockaddr_in clientaddr;
};

int main(int argc, char const** argv) {
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    char msgBuffer[MAXLINE];

    Server server;
    Client client;

    if (sockfd == -1) {
        std::cout << "Create socket error " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
    }

    server.doBind(argc, argv);

    client.doListen(4);

    client.doAccept();

    client.msgProcess(msgBuffer);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The statement

```
memset(&msgBuffer, 0, sizeof(msgBuffer));
```

have *two* problems:

1. `&msgBuffer` is a pointer to the variable `msgBuffer`, it's the wrong pointer to pass if you want to clear the memory where `msgBuffer` is pointing.
2. `sizeof(msgBuffer)` is the size of the *pointer itself*, not whatever array or other data it might point to. You need to pass the size of the array as an argument to the `msgProcess` function.

The first problem you also have with the call to `recv`.

---

You also have plenty of other problems. Like the global variables, setting the signal handlers in a loop inside a function, and possible more.

Comment: thank you for your patience, you are right, I do have a lot mistakes lol, I'm fixing them, and still, thanks for telling me where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

```
         memset(&msgBuffer, 0, sizeof(msgBuffer));
```

The above line sets the local pointer `msgBuffer` to all 0, essentially a `nullptr`.

```
         recv(clientfd, &msgBuffer, MAXLINE, 0);
```

Then this tries to read data into the local pointer variable (not where it points to, but the variable itself). The problem is, pointer size is probably 8 bytes, while MAXLINE as well as your message is probably longer, resulting in buffer overflow.

What you need to do is this:

```
         // zero memory pointed to by msgBuffer, assume it is this size
         memset(msgBuffer, 0, MAXLINE); 

         // receive into memory pointed to by msgBuffer
         recv(clientfd, msgBuffer, MAXLINE, 0);
```

Additionally, you must check return value of `recv` both to detect errors and to know how many bytes were actually received! Store it into a variable so you can examine it for both. After you do this, the above `memset` is kind of redundant, you don't need to care what the "unused" bytes are, but zeroing out the buffer as matter of principle is ok as a means to have more robust code.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `msgBuffer` is not a null terminated char array, so if you receive 1024 bytes you will run into segfault even after you zero the array correctly because `cout` is expecting a null at the end.

a better option is to use [write](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write) `std::cout.write(msgBuffer,MAXLINE)`